# Configured SSL on Tomcat 8 and Connection Times Out

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat8, tls1.2

I setup a keystore and got a SSL cert from openssl.com. The exact steps I followed are here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PUGo7cBLcDTzdkc0pzT2pTMk0/view?usp=sharing

Unfortunately even after following their instructions for tomcat exactly and working with customer support my https connection times out.

It seems like tomcat is up and running, listening on port 443, but I don't know how to debug deeper. Http requests are served just fine, so I know tomcat itself is working just fine.

```
[ec2-user@ip- logs]$ sudo netstat -tunlp | grep 443 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      19407/java

[ec2-user@ip- logs]$ ps -ef | grep java 
root     19407     1  1 23:03 pts/0    00:00:06 /usr/java/jre1.8.0_60//bin/java
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26//conf/logging.properties
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26//endorsed -classpath /usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26//bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/ -Dcatalina.home=/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/apache-tomcat-8.0.26//temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start ec2-user 19449 18021  0 23:13 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

My connector is configured as:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" KeystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/.keystore" KeystorePass="password" />
```

Please help!

Comment: does the timeout occur after 30 seconds??

Comment: Just a little bit less. It was about 25 seconds. ;)

Comment: You could specify asyncTimeout (connector tags attribute). The default timeout for asynchronous requests in milliseconds. If not specified, this attribute is set to the Servlet specification default of 30000 (30 seconds).

Comment: Are you saying that maybe the issue is the server is responding slow and it times out before the request completes, therefore I should set a longer timeout? Seems odd - my http end point responds instantly... I set asyncTimeout="60000" and it still timed out after 25 seconds...

Comment: Ya..somethuig like that..In your connector tag, the default timeout is 30 seconds  as it is not specified. Also check if ssl connection takes place. See [Check SSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755170/setting-up-tomcat-ssl-failed-cannot-connect-to-ssl-channel)

Comment: @EvaMariam Hello Eva, I am actually having a similar problem. When I launch my application locally and send a request through a rest service, the processing in my application takes around 4 minutes and then I get a response. But When I deploy the same piece of code in load environment and try to hit my endpoint using the same rest service, for some reason within one minute the rest service tells me that service didn't respond but in really the server is still processing the request. The UI gets this -> {"responseCode":1000,"responseText":"Generic.exception.message"}. can you please help.

Comment: @EvaMariam Do you think maybe the load environment is configured to evict or release idle connections. Because I feel that since the processing is happening in the backend and the connection is not doing anything correct? So does the server assume its idle and kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I configure tomcat, if there's a delay before I see any response, it is almost always because the PORT is blocked for some reason.  Are you positive port 443 is open through the firewall (assuming this is being done on an external server)?

If your standard port works fine but 443 just sits and spins for a period of time before failing, I'd put my money on a blocked port.

Comment: OMG DUH. This must be it. It's an EC2 instance and I only opened port 80. I will test!

Comment: We've all been there.  I hope that was it.

Comment: Seriously I banged my head against the wall all night long and this fixed it. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 1):

First ensure the 8443 is open,443 is the port reserved for https,you can use it for tomcat,but I prefer to use 8443 or another port different from 443 to avoid conflict with httpd https.
For testing from outside

```
telnet yourserver 8443
```

Must connect,if not check the firewall.
Then check permission of your certificates,pem or keystore(depend from your configuration) must be readable from group or user which run tomcat(on debian is tomcat8,on fedora simply tomcat).

For example,this is my configuration of /etc/tomcat/server.xml

```
 <!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
    <Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/etc/tomcat/keystore" keystorePass="ooops"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

The keystore perms

```
ls -lh /etc/tomcat/keystore 
-r--r-----. 1 tomcat tomcat 2,6K 20 dic 01.06 /etc/tomcat/keystore
```

The port 8443 is open,and I can connect without problem